# In Swift why isn't an Array of Strings convertible to MutableCollectionType?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, collections

I'm trying to mock an object for testing and my overridden return value is not compiling with this error "[String] is not convertible to 'C'"

Here is the mock's function override, and you can see I want to return an array of strings:

```
override func list<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Index == Int>(var list: C) -> C {
    return ["the dog that worried", "the malt that lay in"]
}
```

I've verified that Array conforms to `MutableCollectionType`:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable, _DestructorSafeContainer {
```

Why am I getting this error?